# Unable to disable the hardware prefetcher

Tags: prefetch

I am trying to disable the hardware prefetcher to run some memory benchmarks on an Intel core i5 2500. The problem is that there is no option whatsoever in my BIOS to enable or disable the prefetcher. So I am trying to use msr-tools to disable the prefetcher. But msr-tool is failing to write some specific values to the required register (0x1a0h).

```
$ rdmsr -p 0 0x1a0
850089

$ wrmsr -p 0 0x1a0 0x850289
wrmsr: CPU 0 cannot set MSR 0x000001a0 to 0x0000000000850289
```

This is the same case for all cpus. But if I try to write the value 0x850088 (simply chosen for testing) it will successfully write that value.

Can anyone point out as to where the problem is and what is the solution for this?

Also I felt weird that there is no prefetcher disabling option in my BIOS. Is this the situation with some version of BIOS?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing one of the most relevant details: what is your motherboard?

Comment: Gigabyte H67M-D2-B3

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145857/unable-to-disable-the-hardware-prefetcher